# Scope of a object/variable during method calls

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here in the below example, dataframe `df` is passed from `method_1` to `method_2`. Additional column is added to original dataframe `df` in `method_2()` , but `method_2()` does not return the changed dataframe `df`. But changed dataframe is still reflecting in `method_1()` when we print after the call. Please, can someone help me understand the behaviour?

```
import pandas as pd
class myclass:
    
    def method_1(self):
        data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]}
        # Create DataFrame
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        
        print("BEFORE=",df)
        self.method_2(df)
        print("AFTER=",df)   ## Here this captures changed dataframe although we dont return
        
    def method_2(self, df):
        df['newval'] = 1    ## Here we are not explicitly returning  
    
a = myclass()
a.method_1()
```

Comment: ``df['newval'] = 1`` isn't changing a variable, it changes an object. Objects don't have scope, they have identity.

Comment: You are accessing object as reference, means mutable type, this is the reason why you are obtaining unexpected result.